# Can one set multiple properties inside an object literal to the same value?

Tags: javascript, properties, object-literal

For example, can I do this?:

```
{ 
   a: b: c: d: 1,
   e: 2,
   geh: function() { alert("Hi!") }
}
```

EDIT:
Is there some way I can avoid doing this?:

```
{ 
   a: 1,
   b: 1,
   c: 1,
   d: 1,
   e: 2,
   geh: function() { alert("Hi!") }
}
```

Comment: @LewsTherin - Just did, see edit

Comment: Not sure, but you may have to declare the fields and do a chained assignment.

Comment: Inside an object literal you can't. Outside of it you can do a chain-assignment like `obj.a = obj.b = obj.c = obj.d = 1`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could set a line of equality between various properties:

```
var foo = {};
foo.a = foo.b = foo.c = "Hello";
```

Or you could just create a method that does the mass-assignment for you:

```
var foo = {
    setValue: function( props, value ) {
        while ( props.length ) this[ props.pop() ] = value;
    }
}

foo.setValue( [ "a", "b", "c" ] , "Foo" );
```

Comment: Your first example won't work. You'll get a *TypeError* because `foo` has not yet been assigned the object, so it still has the `undefined` value.

Comment: @user1689607 I was shocked that it worked when I was hacking around in my console; apparently I forgot I had already declared `foo` with an `a` property prior to running that code.

Comment: I've made the same mistake in the console.

Answer (score 30):

An update to this (in terms of the latest JavaScript abilities) avoiding unwanted defined vars:

```
{
  let v;
  var obj = {
     "a": (v = 'some value'),
     "b": v,
     "c": v
  };
}
```

This will mean `v` won't be defined outside the block, but `obj` will be.

#### Original answer

Another way of doing the same thing is:

```
var v;
var obj = {
     "a": (v = 'some value'),
     "b": v,
     "c": v
};
```

Comment: This solution is great. It also works when the object is anonymously defined, e.g. as a direct parameter when calling a function.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this. It's not the syntactic sugar you're looking for (eg. `{a,b,c:1, d:2}`) but it's another way to do it, although all of these answers are pretty much fine.

```
(object,fields,value)=>Object.assign(object||{}, ...fields.map(f=>({[f]:value}) ))
```

**Explanation:**

```
(object,fields,value)=>
```

Takes an object (or falsey value if you want a new object, feel free to rearrange the argument order)

```
Object.assign(object||{},
```

Will return an object based on `object` *and* it will mutate the object. To disable this, simply add a first argument object literal like this `Object.assign({}, object || {}, ...`

```
...fields.map(f=>({[f]:value}) )
```

Will spread the array of fields mapped to objects as a list of extra arguments to `Object.assign`. `['a','b'].map(f=>({[f]:value}) )` will give `[{a:value}, {b:value}]` and `f(...[{a:1},{b:1}])` is like `f({a:1},{b:1})`. `Object.assign` does the rest :)

Answer (score 2):

There's yet another approach: using a mapping function...

```js
// This will be standard! 
if (!Object.fromEntries)
  Object.fromEntries = entries => entries.reduce ((o, [key, value]) => ({
     ...o,
     [key]: value
  }), {})


const setSameValue = (source, props, value) => ({
  ...source,
  ...Object.fromEntries (
     props.map (prop => [prop, value])
  )
})

// The important part: do what you want with ease!
const output = setSameValue ({}, ['1', '01'], 'string 1')

const obj = { x: 1, y: 'hello' }

const output2 = setSameValue (obj, ['1', '01'], 'string1')

console.log ('output1:', output)
console.log ('output2:', output2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap in a closure too, if you didn't want multiple local vars. This syntax seems to be popular (but ugly):

```
var obj = (function() { var v='some value'; return { a:v, b:v, c:v }; })();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `for of` loop instead.

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(object_name)) {
        object_name[key] = 0; // the value that you want to assign
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or yet another way:

```
{...['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].reduce((obj,prop)=>({...obj, [prop]: 1}), {}) }
```

It can be wrapped up pretty neatly by extending the Array prototype:

```
Array.prototype.ditto = function(v) { return this.reduce((o,p)=>({...o, [p]: v}), {}) }
```

So now it can be used like this:

```
{ 
    ...['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].ditto(1),
    ...['e', 'f'].ditto(2)
    geh: function() { alert("Hi!") }
}
```

Explanation: the `.reduce` starts off with an empty object `{}` and for each element `prop` return an object which is whatever was in the object already `...obj` plus a new property with our value 1: `[prop]: 1`. Then expand these properties into the outer object with the `...` at the start.

If you had tons of properties reduce wouldn't be the most efficient, but you could change it to:

```
Array.prototype.ditto = function(v) { let o = {}; this.forEach(p => o[p] = v); return o; }
```

More readable and more efficient but less cool??