# JavaScript Object declaration by combining two different keys

Tags: javascript, object, key, literals

I'm not sure if it's possible or not. So here I'm looking for an answer.

Is there any way to declare an object like:

```
var objectName = {
    key1      : 'value1',

    key2,key3 : 'value2;
}
```

I'm trying to combine `key2` and `key3` together.

Comment: Combine as in assing same value to two different keys or combining two keys to get a single key?

Comment: what's wrong with `var objectName = {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: 'value2',
    key3: 'value2'
}`?

Comment: Objective is to assign same value to two different keys.

Comment: `Objective is to assign same value to two different keys` then do so, like suggested ... value2 is the same as value2, no?

Comment: or `var objectName = { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}; objectName.key3 = objectName.key2;`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts there is nothing wrong with the suggested solution. Currently I have done the same. It's just a nostalgic thought If we could do something like that. Does JS supports it?

Comment: @SanjayJoshi short answer, no.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to assign the values like Patric Roberts says, create an array of keys and set the same value to those keys like so:

```js
var obj = {};
obj['key1'] = 1;

// Array of keys
var arrayOfKeys = ['key2','key3','key4'];
// Common value for keys in array
var val = 2;

// Iterate the array
for(var k in arrayOfKeys) {
  obj[arrayOfKeys[k]] = val;
}
console.log(obj);
```

---

You can also check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104949/can-one-set-multiple-properties-inside-an-object-literal-to-the-same-value)

Comment: `for(var k of arrayOfKeys) { obj[k] = val; }` seems a little cleaner, though this is still very overkill

Answer (score 0):

You could use a slightly different approach, which will work on primitive values, too, by adding an object for keeping the same reference to different keys in the array. For example, you have a value object, like

```
temp = {
    value: 42
}
```

and an array, like

```
object = {
    key2: temp,
    key3: temp
}
```

then you can use the keys independently for the value of the referenced object.

To change the value, you need to address it with

```
object.key2.value = 2000;
console.log(object.key3.value); // 2000
```